# Html table rows getting bigger if I add a picture after table in yandex mail client

Tags: html, email, outlook

When I post e-mail from microsoft outlook program to yandex mail account using following code I get this result: http://prnt.sc/acwmzo (Everything is okey)

```
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <table width="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    England
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    France
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    Germany
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <p></p><!--Picture pasting line -->
                    </body>
                </html>
```

I want to paste a picture after the that table.

When I paste picture after that table and sent e-mail again I get this result: http://prnt.sc/acwz6g

As you can see html table rows getting bigger if I add a picture after table.

Please note that;

there is no problem sending mail from outlook to outlook,

there is no problem sending mail from outlook to gmail,

there is no problem sending mail from outlook to yahoo.

By the way I tried div tag to put table rows stable but it doesnt work.

You can go free yandex mail client from following link.
https://www.yandex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a pain when it comes to images. Most of the e-mail clients adjust the image scale based on one of the attributes width or height. In your code you only mention width. Outlook requires both style attributes to be attached. additionally if your image is greater then 300px width then it will re-adjust the size of the table.

The best suggestion I could recommend would be to do the following:

```
<html>
                    <body>
                        <table width="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    England
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    France
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    Germany
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <img src="*" style="width:290px;height:290px;" alt="image content"/><!--Picture pasting line -->
                    </body>
                </html>
```

This would allow space for the image to be placed below the table. You don't need the paragraph to hold the image you can put it directly into the body. Additionally using this structure for emails, you should watch out for alignment issues.